# Second Monitor not detected in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 as Dualboot on my Laptop, and it does not recognize my second monitor. It works just fine, if I am using Windows.

The Graphics Card is a Nvidia GTX 960m

Secure boot is disabled

I have searched for quite some time, but couldn't find a solution in any of the previous/similar threads.

[Image of Settings->Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwCT.png)

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff memory:60000000-61ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:131 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have tried to install different drivers from Software&Updates->Additional Drivers,

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

and also added PPA and installed the recommended drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

I then installed another driver, but that didn't change anything.

After running these Commands the monitor is in mirror mode, but it shows up as disconnected in xrandr

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
```

I also installed lightdm with no changes.

Does anyone have any possible ideas?
Please also comment, if you need any further information

Comment: Open Nvidia X Server Settings and make sure the Nvidia profile is selected - external monitors ONLY work with the discrete GPU - and reboot if necessary. Meanwhile STOP messing with drivers and don't add unnecessary PPAs. UNDERSTAND how to toggle graphics instead (the Windows driver does that seemingly, the Linux driver doesn't).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I changed it from "NVIDIA On-Demand" to "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" but that didn't change anything. I also previously tried to switch between Intel and NVIDIA Graphics with `sudo prime-select nvidia` and `sudo prime-select intel` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3):

I also try different ways, you can test with different drivers, I try with 525-open and it didn't work, so I change to 515, I reboot it and it works

[image]

Comment: That's what worked for me also after reinstalling the driver with `sudo apt reinstall nvidia-driver-525` not sure what did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I ran the following commands and then reboot, and second monitor was detected.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very common issue that is also very situation specific.

In my case, I have both a built in Intel and external nvidia graphics. I had tried multiple things before I got it working properly.

**Steps**

1. Switch from lightdm to gdm - The effectiveness of using lightdm as the display manager over gdm has been documented [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/cdxjks/using_lightdm_with_an_external_monitor_on_a/) (although this was only an issue in a different flavor of Linux). Note that this is not an absolutely necessary step.
2. It is highly likely that the HDMI will be disconnected which is why the external monitor is not getting detected. You could check this using xrandr.
3. Install appropriate nvidia driver. The one recommended in the ubuntu S/W center did not work for me. Instead I used the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` to check the list of compatible drivers and followed it up with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-[your_version]`.
4. Switch from Intel graphics to NVIDIA graphics - As mentioned in the previous comments, this can be done by `sudo prime-select nvidia` followed by a reboot. If there is no driver, you would be unable to switch. If the incorrect driver was installed, the gui won't open even on the main screen.
5. If the incorrect driver version was installed, the gui may not open. Navigate to the terminal using `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and purge all the current driver version using `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` and reinstall a different version of the driver. Note that having a single driver version and removing all the others is highly recommended. Ideally, you should be able to run `nvidia-smi` after a correct installation. Finding the right driver version seemed to be the crucial step for me.
6. Output of xrandr after installation of correct driver

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1260, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+180 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00 ... 

eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+ 144.00    60.00 ...
```

Comment: Why switch from lightdm if Ubuntu is using gsm by default?

Comment: @Pilot6 The original question did mention that they had tried installing `lightdm`.  Could be why it was mentioned in this answer.  I get that the "switch from" sounds a bit odd, though.