# Ubuntu Crashing: Trying to Determing Cause

Tags: crash

Last night Ubuntu effectively crashed on me. I was running the following applications:

- Firefox
- VSCodum
- Citrix Browser
- Zoom
- Signal
- Terminal

Specifics:

- Three monitor setup; during the event, I couldn't move my mouse from the left screen to the middle and right screen; it was as if it were "stuck" at the border.
- Apps were non responsive, but then I could occasionally hear others in the zoom call-re the zoom call, I wouldn't hear someone for a while, and then they would speed up really fast-newly assembled PC (two days ago)

  - very, very careful during assembly
  - 8 cores
  - 32 GB ram
  - liquid cooling-MSI bios shoes all hardware is functioning as designed. CPU temps are constantly low.
- fully upgraded (`sudo apt upgrade`)
- full updated (`sudo apt update`)
- no details in `/var/crash`

This has only happened ONE time. I've been watching my system resources carefully and haven't seen a heavy strain on CPU or memory.

`/var/log/syslog` had this information. I've tried to summarize it:

```
Apr 20 21:10:55 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49239.013986] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: disp: chid 0 stat 00007a22 reason 7 [UNRESOLVABLE_HANDLE] mthd 2888 data 0004020c code 00000000
Apr 20 21:10:55 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49239.029746] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: disp: chid 0 stat 10001000 reason 1 [PUSHBUFFER_ERR] mthd 0000 data 00000000 code 00000000
Apr 20 21:10:57 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49241.001778] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout
Apr 20 21:10:59 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49243.067653] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout
Apr 20 21:11:01 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49245.067681] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:03 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49247.067844] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:05 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49249.077137] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:07 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49251.082537] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout
Apr 20 21:11:09 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49253.082574] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:11 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49255.082754] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:13 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49257.082881] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:11:15 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49259.082996] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout............
Apr 20 21:12:48 jessedc42-MS-7C95 at-spi2-registr[60190]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
Apr 20 21:12:48 jessedc42-MS-7C95 at-spi2-registr[60190]: Unable to register client with session manager
Apr 20 21:12:50 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49354.361708] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout
Apr 20 21:12:52 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49356.361736] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:12:54 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49358.361850] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:12:56 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49360.361954] nouveau 0000:2b:00.0: DRM: wndw-0: timeout
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362166]

------------[ cut here ]------------

Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362169] WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 90711 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/dispnv50/disp.c:213 nv50_dmac_wait+0x1f5/0x250 [nouveau]
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362207] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek bnep nouveau snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec mt7921e snd_usbmidi_lib mxm_wmi mt7921_common snd_hda_core drm_ttm_helper snd_hwdep mt76_connac_lib btusb ttm btrtl kvm snd_pcm mt76 btbcm drm_display_helper btintel crct10dif_pclmul btmtk ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi binfmt_misc aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event cec mac80211 bluetooth snd_rawmidi rc_core nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo crypto_simd snd_seq drm_kms_helper videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device rapl input_leds videobuf2_v4l2 ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit cfg80211 wmi_bmof ecc videobuf2_common fb_sys_fops snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect k10temp videodev sysimgblt snd ccp joydev video mc soundcore libarc4 mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport ramoops pstore_blk
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362240]  reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic nvme usbhid hid crc32_pclmul r8169 i2c_piix4 nvme_core ahci realtek xhci_pci libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_amdpt
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362248] CPU: 14 PID: 90711 Comm: kworker/u64:2 Not tainted 5.19.0-40-generic #41~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362249] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C95/B550M PRO-VDH WIFI (MS-7C95), BIOS 2.D0 12/12/2022
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362250] Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362273] RIP: 0010:nv50_dmac_wait+0x1f5/0x250 [nouveau]

Apr 20 21:12:58 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49362.362293] Code: 8d 48 04 48 89 4a 68 c7 00 00 00 00 20 49 8b 47 38 41 c7 87 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 49 89 47 68 e8 b0 fc ff ff e9 67 fe ff ff <0f> 0b b8 92 ff ff ff e9 de fe ff ff 49 8b bf 80 00 00 00 e8 93 fc............Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362425] WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 90711 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/dispnv50/disp.c:213 nv50_dmac_wait+0x1f5/0x250 [nouveau]
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362465] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek bnep nouveau snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec mt7921e snd_usbmidi_lib mxm_wmi mt7921_common snd_hda_core drm_ttm_helper snd_hwdep mt76_connac_lib btusb ttm btrtl kvm snd_pcm mt76 btbcm drm_display_helper btintel crct10dif_pclmul btmtk ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi binfmt_misc aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event cec mac80211 bluetooth snd_rawmidi rc_core nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo crypto_simd snd_seq drm_kms_helper videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device rapl input_leds videobuf2_v4l2 ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit cfg80211 wmi_bmof ecc videobuf2_common fb_sys_fops snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect k10temp videodev sysimgblt snd ccp joydev video mc soundcore libarc4 mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport ramoops pstore_blk
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362497]  reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic nvme usbhid hid crc32_pclmul r8169 i2c_piix4 nvme_core ahci realtek xhci_pci libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_amdpt
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362505] CPU: 14 PID: 90711 Comm: kworker/u64:2 Tainted: G        W         5.19.0-40-generic #41~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362507] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C95/B550M PRO-VDH WIFI (MS-7C95), BIOS 2.D0 12/12/2022
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362508] Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Apr 20 21:13:00 jessedc42-MS-7C95 kernel: [49364.362532] RIP: 0010:nv50_dmac_wait+0x1f5/0x250 [nouveau]
```

Does anyone have any recommendations or thoughts?

EDIT: Hardware is fully outlined here:
System:
-Host: jessedc42-MS-7C95 Kernel: 5.19.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64
-Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
-Machine:
-Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: B550M PRO-VDH WIFI (MS-7C95) -v: 1.0
-serial:  UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: 2.D0
date: 12/12/2022
-CPU:
-Info: 8-core AMD Ryzen 7 5700X [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 2275
min/max: 2200/4662
-Graphics:
Device-1: NVIDIA GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] driver: -nouveau
v: kernel
-Device-2: SunplusIT CODi A05022 Webcam type: USB
driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
-Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: -fbdev,vesa
gpu: nouveau resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
3: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.2.5
-Network:
Device-1: MEDIATEK driver: mt7921e
Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
driver: r8169
-Drives:
Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 14.89 GiB (0.8%)
-Info:
Processes: 365 Uptime: 8h 12m Memory: 31.27 GiB used: 2.99 GiB (9.6%)
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13

The version of Ubuntu I’m running is 22.04

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you're running and perhaps some specifics about which hardware is in your machine? This may make it easier for someone to identify a possible issue.

Comment: Since the logs mention "nouveau", I would guess this error has something to do with GPU and the nouveau video driver? Considering that the nouveau driver is an open-source and reverse engineered driver, it shouldn't be all that surprising if some issues pop up once in a while.

Comment: I've seen similar on my laptop with an AMD CPU/GPU. The common factor is Zoom. It's a resource pig, and will happily cause weird GPU issues and hang the entire desktop. Seen it many times. Not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: *nods* zoom had been banned where I work for the same reason.

Comment: I'd try installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and see if that clears things up. It looks like the Nouveau NVIDIA driver is throwing a tantrum. And if you're using an NVIDIA 3060 card, you probably want the additional features the proprietary driver comes with - your card is essentially crippled with the Nouveau driver. You should be able to find the good drivers for your card by opening "Software & Updates" in the application menu, then clicking "Additional Drivers".

Comment: Okay, I'd like to pick y'all's brain a little bit more while you're here. I tried installing the latest video driver for my GEForce 3060. It worked, with the exception of it being unable to detect my other two monitors. So, I reverted back to nouveau. Does anyone else have suggestions?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 Sorry, I didn't see your comment until I had already posted mine. Maybe you can provide some guidance. Please read my most recent post. I was sure to run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade AFTER installing the Nvidia proprietary driver. Still wouldn't detect my other monitors.

Comment: @JesseC. Try searching for "Display" in the application menu. This should pull up a button that lets you configure your displays. See if you need to enable or otherwise move around the other two displays.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 Okay, I just got home. I believe I checked that before, but perhaps I missed something. I'm following some steps found here as well. I'll let you know what happens: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431915/second-monitor-not-detected-in-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I believe this may've resolved the issue. This is assuming that the open-source Nouveau display driver was the primary cause of the problem of course.

Initially, I attempted to use the NVIDIA open kernel driver (530) at the top of list this, but despite my best efforts - disabling secure boot, cycling the monitors, ensuring all was updated - my two side monitors were not being detected.

But then after attempting the other open kernel NVIDIA driver version, I decided that I'd shoot from the hip and try the 530 metapackage - it worked! All three of my monitors are working, and I was able to keep secure boot enabled.

It remains to be seen if Zoom will be a significant chugger in the future, but as of right now memory and CPU are showing very low usage. Thanks everyone!

Warm Regards,
Jesse